# jquery function only looping twice (should be infinite)

Tags: jquery

Hello Stack i have the below code and it only seems to loop once, i cant seem to work out why it will not loop infinitely.

Do you know whats wrong?

here is the demo: http://www.prosperitymedia.co.uk/other/

```
 $( function() {

    function doAnimation() {

    $('#ochreWrapper img').hide();
    $('#ochreTextOne, #ochreTextTwo, #ochreTextThree').hide();

    var displayIDs = "img#imgPisa, img#imgBankChina, img#imgSydney, img#imgPetronas, img#imgBooks, img#imgKremlin, img#imgBridge, img#imgEmpire, img#imgLetterbox, img#imgTrafficLight, img#imgPavement, img#imgOchre, img#imgStephensTower, img#imgClouds, img#imgBus, img#imgRickshaw, img#imgPlane, img#imgPeople, img#imgWoman, img#swooshOne, img#swooshTwo, img#swooshThree";


    $(displayIDs).css('display', 'block');
    $(displayIDs).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);



    //s1
    $('img#imgPisa').css({ "bottom" : "-30px"}).animate({ "bottom": "0", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );
    $('img#imgSydney').css({ "bottom" : "-40px" }).animate({ "bottom" : "0", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );
    $('img#imgPavement').css({ "bottom" : "0" }).animate({ "bottom" : "3%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );

    //s2
    $('img#imgBankChina').css({ "bottom" : "-30px"}).delay(500).animate({ "bottom": "0", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );
    $('img#imgPetronas').css({ "bottom" : "5%"}).delay(500).animate({ "bottom": "12.1%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );
    $('img#imgLetterbox').css({ "bottom" : "-20px"}).delay(500).animate({ "bottom": "0%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );
    $('img#imgClouds').css({ "left" : "0"}).delay(500).animate({ "left": "0%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 ).delay(500).animate({ "left": "200px", "opacity" : 1 }, 25000);

    //s3
    $('img#imgKremlin').css({ "bottom" : "25%"}).delay(1000).animate({ "bottom": "34%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );
    $('img#imgOchre').css({ "bottom" : "0"}).delay(1000).animate({ "bottom": "7%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );

    //s4
    $('img#imgBooks').css({ "bottom" : "13%"}).delay(1500).animate({ "bottom": "23%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );
    $('img#imgStephensTower').css({ "bottom" : "12%"}).delay(1500).animate({ "bottom": "22.5%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );

    //s5
    $('img#imgBridge').css({ "bottom" : "36%"}).delay(2000).animate({ "bottom": "46%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );

    //s6
    $('img#imgEmpire').css({ "bottom" : "38%"}).delay(2500).animate({ "bottom": "48.7%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );
    $('img#imgTrafficLight').css({ "bottom" : "-10px"}).delay(2500).animate({ "bottom": "3%", "opacity": 1}, 1000 );

    //s7
    $('img#imgBus').css({ "left" : "5%"}).delay(3000).animate({"opacity" : 1}).animate({ "left": "1000px", "opacity": 1, "bottom" : "50px"}, 7000);
    $('img#imgPlane').delay(3000).animate({"opacity" : 1}).animate({ "left" : "80%", "opacity" : 1, "top" : "-75px" }, 20000);

    //s8
    $('img#imgRickshaw').css({ "left" : "5%"}).delay(4000).animate({"opacity" : 1}).animate({ "left": "1000px", "opacity": 1, "bottom" : "50px"}, 7000);

    //s9
    $('img#imgPeople, img#imgWoman').css({ "bottom" : "-20px" }).delay(10000).animate({"bottom" : "0", "opacity" : 1 }, 1000);

    //s10
    $('#ochreTextOne').delay(10000).fadeIn(1000).delay(10000).fadeOut(500);
    $('img#swooshTwo, img#swooshThree').hide();
    $('img#swooshOne').show().animate({ "opacity" : 1}, 0);
    $('img#swooshOneOverlay').css({ "right" : "0", "display" : "block" }).delay(10000).animate({ "right" : "1500px" }, 3000, function(){ $('img#swooshOne').hide(); $('img#swooshTwo, img#swooshThree').show().animate({ "opacity" : 1}, 0); }).delay(3000).delay(10100).animate({ "right" : "0" }, 3000);
    $('img#swooshTwoOverlay').css({ "right" : "-1500px", "display" : "block" }).delay(10100).animate({ "right" : "0px" }, 3000).delay(3000).delay(10000).animate({ "right" : "-1500px" }, 3000);


    //s11
    $('#ochreTextTwo').css({ "padding-left" : "50px" }).delay(22000).fadeIn(1000).delay(10000).fadeOut(500);


    //s12
    $('#ochreTextThree').css({ "padding-left" : "50px" }).delay(33000).fadeIn(1000).delay(10000).fadeOut(500).delay(0, doAnimation)

    }


    doAnimation();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ...
    setInterval(doAnimation, 1000);    
});
```

This will set it up so `doAnimation` runs every 1 second (decrease the 1000 to decrease the length of the interval - 500 would be half a second, 100 would be a tenth of a second, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You're only calling `doAnimation();` once so it will only run once.

Add a call to `doAnimation()` at the end of the doAnimation function to loop indefinitely:

```
      //s12
      $('#ochreTextThree').css({ "padding-left" : "50px" }).delay(33000).fadeIn(1000).delay(10000).fadeOut(500).delay(0, doAnimation)


      //Call function again to loop
      doAnimation();  
    }

    doAnimation();

});
```

Comment: so just to confirm i remove the ; on the end of doAnimation(); ?

Comment: @Xavier - added to my answer for clarity :-)

Comment: it does loop now but it loops everything constantly! whereas before it was looping the whole instance twice now it just loops everything like crazy !

Comment: Since this makes the function recursive, this will most likely make the browser (or browser tab) unresponsive. You may get warnings like "A script on this page has become unresponsive. Would you like to stop it? [Yes/No]"

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are only calling the main function once, and in it you only call the doAnimation() function twice. Once where you declare it and once after.